# How to convert xsd:double string to decimal in one step

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, type-conversion, mdxclient

I'm using [MdxClient](https://github.com/DynamicTyped/MdxClient) which internally parses XML documents returned by [`AdomdCommand.ExecuteXmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124391(v=sql.110).aspx). Some of values are returned as `xsd:double`, but I want them as `decimal` at client side.

This library to parse values uses [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx) method. But some of `xsd:double` strings such as `3.514680845402702E1` or `4.058719395866455E1` cannot been converted to `decimal`:

```
var result = Convert.ChangeType("3.514680845402702E1", typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

throws `FormatException`.

I know I can convert it in two steps:

```
var tmp = Convert.ChangeType("3.514680845402702E1", typeof(double), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result2 = Convert.ChangeType(tmp, typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible in one step? Maybe by providing custom [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation as third argument? Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with parsing it as `double`, then casting to `decimal`? If you can change the invocation to `Convert.ChangeType()`, then surely you can stick a cast in front of it as well, or am I missing something obvious? Writing a custom `FormatProvider` just so you can coax `Convert.ChangeType()` into doing it for you seems rather roundabout.

Comment: @JeroenMostert method AdjustValueFromColumnType from https://github.com/DynamicTyped/MdxClient/blob/master/MdxClient/MdxCommand.cs is used to convert many types. I've changed it to sth similar to if (IsDecimalFixNeeded(resultSetType, cellType)) {FirstConvert();} Convert(); but I think that one convert will be more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use `Convert.ChangeType(...)`?

If you simply want to convert a string containing a number formatted in Exponential Notation, you can do the following:

```
var result = decimal.Parse("3.514680845402702E1", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```